# CSS rule for grandchild irrespective of its parent element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have css rule as follows,

```
.wrapper > h3{
        color:red;
    }
```

The html code,

```
<div class='wrapper'>
      <h3>Text1</h3>
    </div>

    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div data-ui-view=''>
          <h3>Text2</h3>        
      </div>      
    </div>
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZSHwbbDWc4RaGFeVcJPb?p=preview). The `Text1` is shown in red colour but `Text2` is not. I understood that this rule 
will take the immediate `<h3>` element under `.wrapper`. In angularjs most of the time the elements will be wrapped under  tag. So, I want to make a rule such that whenever an `<h3>` tag comes inside `.wrapper` class then it has to be in red colour. irrespective of `<h3>`'s parent elements. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply make the rule:

```
.wrapper h3 { color: red; }
```

This will make all `<h3>` elements within the `.wrapper` class red

If you did want to target the grandchild element as your question title suggests you could use this rule:

```
.wrapper > * > h3 { color: red; }
```

Comment: This comes in super-handy when styling Table Elements because under `table` is `tbody`, `thead`, or `tfoot`, then after that is `tr`, and then after that are the `th` and `tr` Elements I'm targeting, so I could then use `.wrapper>*>*>*` to style only the Cells.  Sure I could use `.wrapper th, .wrapper td` but then if I add an Inner-Table using a different class, I'd have to set/override every corresponding style from the Parent Table.  With this approach I may use a complex class for my Parent Table that will **ONLY** affect Elements for that Table, and a much simpler Class for my Inner Table.